# Applying an unambiguous quantum state discrimination operator on an entangled qubit.

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-computation

Given a quantum system $|\psi\rangle=\alpha_0|\psi_0\rangle\otimes |0\rangle+\alpha_1|\psi_1\rangle\otimes |1\rangle$, such that each subsystem $|\psi_i\rangle$ is entangled with a qubit is state $|i\rangle$.

Is it correct that applying the unambiguous quantum state discrimination operator (USD) $P=I\otimes|0\rangle\langle0|$ on $|\psi\rangle$, where $I$ is the identity operator gives,

$P|\psi\rangle=|\psi_0\rangle\otimes |0\rangle$

Answer (score 0):

We have
$$P\left|\psi\right\rangle
=I\otimes\left|0\right\rangle\left\langle0\right|\left(\alpha_0|\psi_0\rangle\otimes |0\rangle+\alpha_1|\psi_1\rangle\otimes |1\rangle\right)$$
$$=\alpha_0|\psi_0\rangle\otimes\left|0\right\rangle\left\langle0\right|0\rangle
+\alpha_1|\psi_1\rangle\otimes\left|0\right\rangle\left\langle0\right|1\rangle
=\alpha_0|\psi_0\rangle\otimes\left|0\right\rangle$$
if the states $\left|0\right\rangle$ and $\left|1\right\rangle$ are orthogonal (and then $\left\langle0\right|1\rangle=0$).

Comment: The result cannot be $\alpha_0|\psi_0\rangle\otimes |0\rangle$ because $|\alpha_0|^2+|\alpha_1|^2=1$ unless $\alpha_0=1$ before applying $P$ and in this case, $P$ didn't do any change of $|\psi\rangle$.

Comment: Yet the answer is mathematically correct. Since $P$ is a linear operator, since the tensor product is bilinear, the coefficient $\alpha_0$ must appear at the end of the calculus.

Comment: The operator is a projective measurement, so we should normalize.

Comment: Nothing tells us to normalize mathematically, and I do not see a physical reason to do this. $|\alpha_0|^2$ will be the probability to have the above state, and it can be less than $1$.

Comment: For example, $\left|0\right\rangle$ and $\left|1\right\rangle$ can be two states of polarization of a photon, and $|\alpha_0|^2$ gives you the probability that your photon will be polarized with respect to $\left|0\right\rangle$, and it can be $1/2$ if, for example, the both directions of polarization are $\pi/4$ compared to the original direction.

Comment: After we apply measurement, one of the states disappear from the superposition and the probability of the remaining state should be equal 1. The state can't be alone in the superposition with probability less than 1. $|\alpha_0|^2$ is the probability to find $| 0 \rangle$ before applying measurement. If we applied measurement and found $| 0 \rangle$ then the probability of any future measurement will 1 to find $| 0 \rangle$. Any way, this is the case of the protective measurement. My question is about USD.

Comment: Ok if you consider the NEW system which consists in the projected state on $\left|\psi_0\right\rangle\otimes\left|0\right\rangle$ : we need to have a normalized state. But if you consider the original system, you must take in consideration the other component of your state (the one that has not been projected). So, if your question was to check your state after projection, then I'm agree with your answer.